# Problem building Brave Browser from source

Tags: webpack, brave

I am trying to build Brave on my Mac (Sonoma) and I am running into problem in the  `npm run build release` step.
Specifically, I am following the steps outlined in https://github.com/brave/brave-browser on a release-version of brave checked out and not altered in any way.

I ran into multiple problems with nodes modules not being installed correctly, which I was able to fix. Now, the problem is the following:

```
~/b/src/brave  ◈ v1.61.109 ±  npm run build release

> brave-core@1.61.109 build
> node ./build/commands/scripts/commands.js build

touch overridden files...
touch original files overridden by chromium_src...
...touch original files overridden by chromium_src done
touch original vector icon files overridden by brave/vector_icons...
...touch original vector icon files overridden by brave/vector_icons done
...touch overridden files done
update branding...
Recursing through GRD to find GRDP files...
Done recursing through GRD to find GRDP files.
...update branding done
generate ninja files...
Widevine cdm host verification is disabled
...generate ninja files done
build brave (id=a2ebb3a2-43c7-4a96-a629-c1a342571dfa)...
ninja brave Component...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/Users/me/b/src
> autoninja -C /Users/me/b/src/out/Component_arm64 brave -k 1 --offline
ninja: Entering directory `/Users/me/b/src/out/Component_arm64'
[4/43027] ACTION //brave/components/brave_adblock_ui/adblock_internals:brave_adblock_internals_ui(//build/toolchain/mac:clang_arm64)
FAILED: gen/brave/web-ui-brave_adblock_internals/brave_adblock_internals.grd
python3 ../../brave/script/transpile-web-ui.py --output_path=gen/brave/web-ui-brave_adblock_internals --root_gen_dir=/Users/me/b/src/out/Component_arm64/gen --grd_name=brave_adblock_internals.grd --resource_name=brave_adblock_internals --depfile_path=/Users/me/b/src/out/Component_arm64/gen/brave/components/brave_adblock_ui/adblock_internals/brave_adblock_internals_ui.d --webpack_alias=chromeapp --entry=brave_adblock_internals=/Users/me/b/src/brave/components/brave_adblock_ui/adblock_internals/brave_adblock_internals.tsx

> brave-core@1.61.109 web-ui
> webpack --config components/webpack/webpack.config.js --colors --mode=development --webpack_alias=chromeapp brave_adblock_internals=/Users/me/b/src/brave/components/brave_adblock_ui/adblock_internals/brave_adblock_internals.tsx

Hash: 27e74e8f6ce60f8c9e4f
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 7797ms
Built at: 02/02/2024 11:40:34 AM
                            Asset      Size                   Chunks             Chunk Names
brave_adblock_internals.bundle.js  2.31 MiB  brave_adblock_internals  [emitted]  brave_adblock_internals
Entrypoint brave_adblock_internals = brave_adblock_internals.bundle.js
[./components/brave_adblock_ui/adblock_internals/brave_adblock_internals.tsx] ./components/brave_adblock_ui/adblock_internals/brave_adblock_internals.tsx + 7 modules 13.5 KiB {brave_adblock_internals} [built]
    | ../out/Component_arm64/gen/ui/webui/resources/tsc/js/cr.js 4.51 KiB [built]
    | ../out/Component_arm64/gen/ui/webui/resources/tsc/js/assert.js 1.26 KiB [built]
    | ../out/Component_arm64/gen/ui/webui/resources/tsc/js/promise_resolver.js 1.28 KiB [built]
    |     + 5 hidden modules
    + 12 hidden modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js 100:37
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (100:37)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|           if (subscriber !== null && interaction.__count === 0) {
>             subscriber.onInteractionS
 @ ./node_modules/scheduler/index.js 6:19-60
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./components/brave_adblock_ui/adblock_internals/brave_adblock_internals.tsx
```

The list continues and throws the same type of error multiple times. Anyhow, a recurring thing is the following error type:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js 100:37
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (100:37)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|           if (subscriber !== null && interaction.__count === 0) {
>             subscriber.onInteractionS
 @ ./node_modules/scheduler/index.js 6:19-60
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js
 @ ./components/brave_adblock_ui/adblock_internals/brave_adblock_internals.tsx
```

It seems that I need to configure webpack to handle `*.tsx` files. Anyhow, I cam unsure about *WHERE* to configure this (i.e. in which file) and to *WHAT* to set *WHICH* parameters.

Some more infos:

- npm version is 10.2.5
- node version is 20.5.1

Anyhow here who might shed some light on this one?

Thanks in advance!